# How to see progress of download started in the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

When downloading software via the terminal is there a way to see the download progress?

I kicked off a download via the terminal and I can't tell if it's progressing or stuck.

Comment: Which command did you run? Different commands have different ways of seeing their progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to install `wget` (e.g. with Homebrew), which has more user-friendly defaults than curl, including displaying an ASCII-art progress bar.

For example:

```
> brew install wget
> wget google.com
Saving to: 'index.html'
...
index.html                      [ <=>              ]  10.32K  --.-KB/s in 0.001s

2016-05-17 12:55:06 (8.08 MB/s) - 'index.html' saved [10563]
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal on your Mac and enter the following command:

```
curl -O <URL  for download>
```

That is a capital "O" not a zero.

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mac-os-x-terminal-download-file/) a nice site with some terminal commands you might like to use.